# Finite index subgroup with free abelianization

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated, nilpotent-groups

Suppose $G$ is a nilpotent, finitely generated group such that it's abelianization has rank $r$. How does one go on proving that $G$ has a finite-index subgroup $H$ with free abelianization of rank $r$?

Comment: Here is a link to the corresponding posts on [mathoverflow.se]: [Finite index subgroup with free abelianization](https://mathoverflow.net/q/73649). (When the questions are posted here and on MO, it is [recommended [to add links to each other](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting#5088)).

Answer (score 3):

The abelianization gives you a surjection $G\twoheadrightarrow G^{ab}\cong\mathbb Z^r\oplus T$, where $T$ is a finite torsion group. (Finite because the abelianization is finitely generated.) Now let $H$ be the inverse image of $\mathbb Z^r$ under this surjection.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, $H^{ab}$ could be $\mathbb Z^r\oplus T_1$. So you repeat the process by taking a finite index subgroup of $H$, say $H_1$. Now it's not hard to show that $G,H,H_1,\ldots$ is a descending central series. That means each term is contained in the corresponding term of the lower central series and the quotients $H_i/H_{i+1}$ are contained in the quotients $\Gamma_i/\Gamma_{i+1}$ of the lower central series, which are eventually trivial.

Comment: That's how I tried to do it, but I'm not able to prove that abelianization of H is free. I mean, could it be that H' is a proper subgroup of G', hence abelianization of the embedding H -> G is not monic?

Comment: $H$ maps onto $\mathbb Z^r$ so its abelianization is at least as big as $\mathbb Z^r$, since any homomorphism to an abelian group factors through its abelianization. Perhaps this is where nilpotency is used, since you can only repeat this process finitely many times.

Comment: I agree, but how do you prove that you can repeat this process only finitely many times>

Comment: You're building a series of nested subgroups whose successive quotients are abelian so that smells like the lower central series, but I admit I don't see the argument at the moment.

Comment: @Jim: Are you using rank in the sense of "minimum number of generators", or in some other sense? If you are, then the rank of $\mathbb{Z}^{r} \oplus T$ is greater than $r$ if the torsion part is non-zero.

Comment: @Geoff: I'm using "rank of an abelian group" to mean the largest copy of $\mathbb Z^r$ inside the group. This is equivalent to the dimension of the group tensored with the rationals as a vector spaces. This is a common usage.